# I'm trying to play m3u8 streaming link but that is not working but when i direct open link it download content

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, jwplayer, m3u8

I have one hls link and I tried to play that link but its not working please help me how I can play this link

https://kusyqmkl.shannon-fisher.xyz/v2/7qRnNzTxDxXyEaAx6asF7a9J7aI/playlist.m3u8

I tried with this command

```
vlc "https://kusyqmkl.shannon-fisher.xyz/v2/7qRnNzTxDxXyEaAx6asF7a9J7aI/playlist.m3u8" :http-user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"
```

and get this output

> adaptive stream: 302 redirection to
>   https://doc-08-ag-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/lonr970b3oiohu1c4h15tfssvr203vb0/1582917675000/14215951100955279466/*/1fwksszFzVo7697_CNm7sr18LssWjZIlE?e=download
>   [00007f958bd13320] adaptive stream error: Failed reading
>   https://doc-08-ag-docs.googleusercontent.com:443/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/lonr970b3oiohu1c4h15tfssvr203vb0/1582917675000/14215951100955279466/*/1fwksszFzVo7697_CNm7sr18LssWjZIlE?e=download:
>   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

if I will direct open that link then it will download following link

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1728000,RESOLUTION=480x360
VzgRO8qROPoiXzsM16CwgSsvKxHPWRqTt5BSYPrff7TJYsFutrlffxIRVLooX7Vk0Qvb/f11832616eaab46b6475cda26e40f549.m3u8
```

is there any way to stream this link?

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

> is there any way to stream this link?

No